# Dealing with multiple arrays processing form

Tags: php, jquery

I seem to keep running into issues trying to get this code to work and I realise its probably a simple solution but for the life of me can't figure it quite out.

I have a form that on the press of a certain button dynamically generates two jquery datepicker fields and two jquery multiselect fields each time the button is pressed.
This functions fine however on the backend when processing the data the two multiselect fields I can only get one thing that has been selected out of each
(Eg. The first multiselect field has the numbers 1,2,3,4. If someone selects more than one of those numbers and hits submit then my script only sees the first number they selected and not each one.

This is the relevant code I am using to process the data:

```
    $b = 1;
    foreach(array_combine($_POST['eventdateFrom'], $_POST['eventdateTo']) as $from => $to){
    echo "<br>";

    $date[$b] = $from."[Periods: ".$_POST['pcFrom'][$b][$b]."] - ".$to."[Periods: ".$_POST['pcTo'][$b][$b]."]";

    $b++;
    }
```

This is the code that the button uses to generate the dynamic fields:

```
    var x=0;
    $('.addmore').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        x++; 


         $('.input_fields_wrap').append('<div class="newDate"><div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-sm-2"><label class="col-form-label-sm" for="inputEmail4">&nbsp;</label></div><div class="form-group col-auto"><label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm" for="inputEmail4">From</label><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm datepicker" id="eventdateFrom' + x + '" name="eventdateFrom[]" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" value=""><select name="pcFrom[' + x + '][' + x + ']" class="pselect" id="pcFrom' + x + '" multiple="multiple"><option selected>All</option><option value="1" >1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option></select></div><div class="form-group col-auto"><label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm" for="inputPassword4">To</label><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm required datepicker" id="eventdateTo' + x + '" name="eventdateTo[]" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" value=""><select name="pcTo[' + x + '][' + x + ']" class="pselect" id="pcTo' + x + '" multiple="multiple"><option selected>All</option><option value="1" >1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option></select></div></div><div class="form-group row"><label for="providerLabel" class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm col-sm-2">&nbsp;</label><div class="col-sm-5"><button type="button" class="form-control-sm required removeDate btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i> Remove Date</button></div></div></div>');

        $('.pselect').multiselect();
        $('.pselect').multiselect('rebuild');

    });

    $(document).on("focus", ".datepicker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
    });

    $('.input_fields_wrap').on("click",".removeDate", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).closest('div.newDate').remove(); x--;
    })
```

Comment: I am unsure what your issue is? when replicating your code I get what I think is your desired output? 

`Array
(
    [1] => 01/01/2020[Periods: All] - 01/15/2020[Periods: 1]
    [2] => 01/28/2020[Periods: 2] - 01/31/2020[Periods: 3]
)`

Comment: If someone selects multiple periods like 1 2 and 3 it will only show the first item that was selected instead of all of them..

Comment: Could you setup an example with the `multiselect` functionality included on [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) it would help to see the issue and possibly help you